# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout Tag Layout with Dynamic Cell Height

Tags: uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am trying to achieve this kind of tag layout (collectionview cells with dynamic width and height) but code crashes with some constraint errors when the text for a label within a cell is very long. is there a way to have a label with multiple lines of text with this kind of layout? how do i restrict the maximum width of a cell to be the widthdimension of the group and also support more than one line of text? also if, for example, the label for item 3 (see image) is going to have two lines of text, i want that cell to wrap around to row 2 and occupy rows 2 and 3. item 4 should then start on row 4.

if multiple lines of text in a label is not possible with this layout, how do i restrict the number of lines in a label to 1 and also restrict width of label to be the widthdimension of the group i.e. truncate the text in a label if it is going to occupy more than one line in the label?

[image]

```
func makeLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (section: Int, environment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(100), heightDimension: .estimated(32))
        let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: itemSize.heightDimension)
        let layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])

        layoutGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(8)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
        section.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 8
            
        return section
    }
    return layout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example your group size is `.fractionalWidth(1)` - which means it is equal to the size of the section.  You can get this value from the container width - which comes from the `environment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment` argument when you are initializing UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.

so you would do something like this in your code:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (section: Int, environment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
    //save this width information somewhere in your class
    let availableWidth: CGFloat = environment.container.effectiveContentSize.width
    ...
    ... //continue to configure your layout normally
}
```

In your cell where you display the label, create a max-width constraint. If you are using Interface Builder, make sure the constraint is connected to an IBOutlet. Here is how to achieve this in Interface Builder. If you are not using IB - then do the same in your code.

[image: interface builder set max width constraint example]

When you are configuring your cell with the text, also configure this max width constraint. Perhaps something like this in your UICollectionViewDelegate:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let tagCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "tagCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? TagCell
    let tagData = backingDataSource[indexPath.item] //imagine there is an array named backingDataSource
    tagCell.configure(with: tagData, maxWidth: self.availableWidth)
    return tagCell
}
```

and finally your TagCell definition looks like this. If you are using SwiftUI, you need to translate this to SwiftUI.

```
class TagCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private weak var tagLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var tagMaxWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    
        tagLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        tagLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        //configure your label according to your needs
    }
    ...
    ...
    
    func configure(with tagData: String, maxWidth: CGFloat) {
        self.tagLabel.text = tagData
        self.tagMaxWidthConstraint.constant = maxWidth
    }
}
```